# Как выполнить проверку

Tags: c++

Мне нужно выполнить проверку и исключить нажатие, при нажатии клавиши отключить нажатие другой клавиши, то есть, если я иду влево, то я не могу пойти направо

Comment: Можно просто объяснить суть, как это должно работать

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, чего Вы хотите добиться...

Comment: Я имею кнопки управления W, A, S, D. При нажатии W, мне нужно исключить нажатие S и её всех функций. Это как в змейке, если ты идёшь вперёд, то ты не можешь пойти назад, ты будешь проходить сквозь себя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну как-то так. Если нажата клавиша S и при этом направление змейки любое отличное от "вверх", то выполнится условие

```
if ((buttonPressed == "S") && (direction != UP))
{

}
```

Т.е. необходима переменная, которая обозначает направление движения. Она у вас должна быть в любом случае для дальнейшего движения и условия приращения координат.